# Visual C++ project dependency on multiple architectures

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a Visual C++ solution with multiple projects. One of the projects (let's name it Project 1) depends on both x86 and x64 versions of another Project 2. It means that when doing a rebuild of Project 1, no matter which architecture is selected I want both x86 and x64 versions of Project 2 to be compiled, prior to Project 1.

Standard Project Dependency feature doesn't allow to specify dependency on multiple architectures. Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I'm sure you can adjust the conditions in your project files to model those dependencies. But since the bitness of all executable modules in a process must match, that's a pretty unusual requirement, and the IDE does not help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual C++ has a command line compiler.

You can execute it on the project you need built, or split your code into multiple slns  and tell the command line to build the slns.

This dependency can be set up as a custom build step, or you could go and write a makefile that describes your project dependencies and replace your sln build with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom Build Step or Custom Build Event to call msbuild twice, once for each architecture. This is how Visual Studio builds projects, so you are effectively recursively calling the build system.

Here's more detailed information:

Understanding Custom Build Steps and Build Events
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k.aspx